# Electrolytic cell - Potentials

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis, cyclic-voltammetry

[image: circuit and potentials schematic - potentiostat (3 electrode system)]

I'm an electronic engineer student and I'm trying to understand the basics of electrolytic cells and practical values' meaning. Based on my figure and electrode potencial values (Vce, Vre and Vwe), can you help me how to describe the following concepts:

- Standard cell potencial
- Equilibrium potential
- Overpotential
- Open circuit potential
- Reference voltage (electrochemical perspective)

EDITED:
Actually I'm asking about **direct** relations between this definitions and circuit voltages **if there are any**

For example, is OCP = Vre when it's not applied external potential?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I didn't get your point, I know how the potentiostat works. I'm asking about electrochemical concepts and relation between them and potentiostat voltages

Comment: Also, it's unclear what the question is. "*Can you help me how to describe the following concepts*" is a vague request suggesting certain amount of tutoring, which is a poor fit for a Q&A site. @EdV made a good point that preliminary literature/internet research might give you a better overview of the topics you've listed. Refer to the [Help Center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help), especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain it right. Actually I'm asking about direct relations between this definitions and circuit voltages if there are any. For example, I think OCP is Vre when its not applied external potencials, is it right?

Comment: Ok, I need to review my question I get it. Btw I'm not asking about electronics. Thank you anyway